# how to check wifi password on iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

How to verify wifi password on iphone with objective-c.I use NetworkExtension/NEHotspotHelper to set wifi Password. So I want to verify the password,set the right password and ignore the wrong password.But I do not know how to figure it out.Is there any way I can try?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Nothing i have tried so far ! Private API may be able to solve this problem。But my app is going to Appstore。

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that. Because, first of all it is not possible to programmatically connect the device to a network(unless your device device is jailbroken and you have to use third party libraries). So it shouldn't have access to network security info also, especially for Wi-Fi password.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.I should give up!